# Tiny_tds: Connect: Server name not found in the configuration files

Tags: ruby, tiny-tds

```
require "rubygems"
require "tiny_tds"

client = TinyTds::Client.new(:username => 'sa', :password => '', :host => 'RICHARD_PC\SQLEXPRESS')
result = client.execute("SELECT * FROM [Contacts]")

result.each do |row|
   //Do something
 end
```

I keep getting the same error: "**Connect: Server name not found in the configuration files**". All I need to do is to be at least be able to connect with Sql Server. So if the host is not the **sqlexpress instance** installed on my machine, what is it then? In the **Github** website it said this **host => 'mydb.host.net'** (:host - Used if :dataserver blank. Can be an host name or IP.)

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either use 
   :dataserver => 'RICHARD_PC\SQLEXPRESS'
Or use
   :host => 'RICHARD_PC', :port => 1433

Answer (score 3):

For those running rails on vagrant, I got this error when my vagrant network connections stopped working (mostly just the DNS), so a reboot fixed the issue.

Comment: I wish I could fix why vagrant does that. It happens all the time.