# Connect Sql server in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu, tiny-tds

I need to connect to a SQL Server database, I installed gem 'tiny_tds' gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter' gem 'deprecated'

my yml file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlserver
  host: basddatos.dyndns.org
  username: zu
  password: pass
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: Basdatos_2016
```

GEMFILE

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

#SQl Server
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
gem 'ruby-odbc'
gem 'deprecated'
gem 'dbd-odbc'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

I get this error: TinyTds::Error Server name not found in configuration files
WHY? thanks

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a full answer but a debugging suggestion (I needed the example space).  Try setting the `development` block in your `database.yml` to:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  host: basddatos.dyndns.org
  username: zu
  password: pass
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  database: Basdatos_2016
```

Do you still get the same error?

Comment: yes my friend, the same error  TinyTds::Error  missing :host option if no :dataserver given

Comment: Would you mind adding the contents of your `Gemfile` to the question?

Comment: maybe the problem is in TinyTds, here is another question but i dont know where to put the code, and in the documentation have the same code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869544/tiny-tds-connect-server-name-not-found-in-the-configuration-files     https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds#freetds-compatibility--configuration

Comment: this code client = TinyTds::Client.new username: 'sa', password: 'secret', host: 'mydb.host.net'

Comment: TinyTDS can definitely be tricky. The code you posted looks okay to me. Just to eliminate the possibility of improperly formatted yaml, could you open up rails console and try the following:  `puts YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'database.yml')).inspect`. It should yield a hash of your database configuration.

Comment: yes, all the configuration of the yml, exactly the same

Comment: now I get this error:
TinyTds::Error  Server name not found in configuration files